# DatePicker and chrome issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-ui

So I have just come across this issue.

I am using the JQuery UI to have a datepicker which "maps" to a readonly textbox:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
            {
                var dateFormatStr = 'yy/mm/dd';
                $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: dateFormatStr,
                    minDate: '-100Y',
                    maxDate: '-18Y',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });

                $('#DateOfBirth').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

And in the View, this is what I am doing to bind it:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

This works fine in IE.

In Chrome however, not so much. It gives its own definition of the date picker control and you can see the jquery control behind it! And when you try to set the value, it fails to do so.

is there a reason why chrome is acting weird? I am guessing this is because the EditorFor is binding the DateOfBirth property which is of type DateTime.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? I believe I had issues when I was using a TextBoxFor instead and had to use the EditorFor.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `Id` with your `EditorFor` statement.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { id="DateOfBirth", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Don't know if that's the issue, I worked on the `datepicker` control yesterday and I had no issues.  Unfortunately, I can't make much sense of what you describe as weird behaviour in Chrome.

Comment: I'll try the Id thing but that isn't really the issue. Try pulling up chrome with somewhat the same View/VM and I am sure you will see the issue.